# Open a spreadsheet in the middle of macro

Tags: vba, excel

Currently, I have a sub which downloads an Excel file from the Internet. I would like to open the spreadsheet and run more commands on it prior to the sub ending.

The issue is that the spreadsheet does not open until the macro has finished executing thus it cannot find the workbook.

```
With appIE
    .Navigate "https://www.alerian.com/wp-content/uploads/AMZmembers.xls"
    .Visible = False

   Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
   SendKeys "{Enter}"
End With

Application.Workbooks("AMZmembers.xls").Close
```

SendKeys "{Enter}" opens the sheet but it will not open until the sub has finished; therefore, Workbooks.close cannot find the sheet because it isn't open yet.

Appreciate help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Workbooks.Open "path_and_filename"` instead of the `SendKeys`. There are a bunch of other parameters in the `Open` method such as whether you want it opened read-only, etc but the simplest way is as shown.